# How to initialize Bot framework dialog in a Luis intent block

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Bot Framework Sample - NLP Dispatch
Hi,
I am using NLP dispatch, where I am having multiple Luis and QnA models running simultaneously. I have mapped top-scoring intents for Luis and have created a dialog class also which I want to implement in those intents mapped blocks. How can I initialize my dialog in the intent if block?

I have tried using Dotnet core 2.1 version and dispatch's latest version

code for dialog -

```
   private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LeaveDateRangeStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var leaveApply = (LeaveApplication)stepContext.Options;

        if (leaveApply.TravelDate == null){
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please Provide me with your Leaves Tenure") }, cancellationToken);
        }
        else{
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(leaveApply.TravelDate, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

intent block

```
if (topIntent == "LeavesDateTenure"){   
    // here I want my dialog to work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in your if statement

```
await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(YourDialogClass));
```

> note - I am assuming your code is inside a RouterDialog and dc is the
>   DialogContext instance

Also, have a look at the Bot Enterprise Template.

Comment: how can i use DialogContext in my intent mapping block?

Comment: Since I am not too sure of your implementation, I could only suggest a possible implementation of the dispatcher. Please check this link https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Customer-Support-Template/CustomerSupportTemplate/Dialogs/Main/MainDialog.cs and see if this sample helps in your case or else share more details of the file containing your intent code block

Comment: for my  intent code  here is the thread for that -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213716/how-to-call-dialog-class-inside-luis-intent-block