# How to call Dialog class inside Luis Intent Block

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using NLP Dispatch , through which i have a merged luis and QnA model, I am able to normally call and add my own logic inside top scoring intents block. Now i have a dialog class which i want to be called whenever a top scoring intent is being detected

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class DispatchBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        private ILogger<DispatchBot> _logger;
        private IBotServices _botServices;

        public DispatchBot(IBotServices botServices, ILogger<DispatchBot> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _botServices = botServices;
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // First, we use the dispatch model to determine which cognitive service (LUIS or QnA) to use.
            var recognizerResult = await _botServices.Dispatch.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
            var topIntent = recognizerResult.GetTopScoringIntent();

            // Next, we call the dispatcher with the top intent.
            await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            const string WelcomeText = "I am here to make your bot experience much more easier";

            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hi {member.Name}, I am your IT assistant at your service . {WelcomeText}"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            switch (intent)
            {
                case "l_mts-bot-809f":
                    await ProcessHomeAutomationAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
                    break;

                case "q_mts-bot":
                    await ProcessSampleQnAAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                default:
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}.");
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}."), cancellationToken);
                    break;
            }
        }
        private Activity CreateResponse(IActivity activity, Attachment attachment)
        {
            var response = ((Activity)activity).CreateReply();
            response.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { attachment };
            return response;
        }

        private async Task ProcessHomeAutomationAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, LuisResult luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ProcessHomeAutomationAsync");

            // Retrieve LUIS result for Process Automation.
            var result = luisResult.ConnectedServiceResult;

            var topIntent = result.TopScoringIntent.Intent;
            var entity = result.Entities;


            if (topIntent == "welcome")
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Hi,This is your IT assistant"), cancellationToken);
            }
            if (topIntent == "None")
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Sorry I didnt get you!"), cancellationToken);
            }

            if (topIntent == "DateTenure")
            {
              // Here i want to call my dialog class
                }

            }



        }



        private async Task ProcessSampleQnAAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ProcessSampleQnAAsync");

            var results = await _botServices.SampleQnA.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext);
            if (results.Any())
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(results.First().Answer), cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, could not find an answer in the Q and A system."), cancellationToken);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

I want as and when my top intent is detected , my custom dialog comes into action and the handling of conversation is then should be handled by my dialog class.

Answer (score 0):

```
private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            switch (intent)
            {
                case "l_mts-bot-809f":
                    //I MADE CHANGES HERE


                    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(DIALOG_CLASS_I_WANT_TO_START));
                    break;

                case "q_mts-bot":
                    await ProcessSampleQnAAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                default:
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}.");
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}."), cancellationToken);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Just remember to add the dialog to either your main dialog class like this:

```
public MainDialog(UserState userState)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog))
        {
            _userState = userState;

            AddDialog(new DIALOG_CLASS_I_WANT_TO_START());

            InitialDialogId = nameof(aDifferentDialogNotShownHere);
        }
```

or to your startup.cs as a transient:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            //all the other configure stuff...

            // Register dialogs
            services.AddTransient<MainDialog>();
            services.AddTransient<DIALOG_CLASS_I_WANT_TO_START>();
```

Comment: you have started a dialog in here "l_mts-bot-809f" ..but after that my luis will handle a single dialog use case only, i am having many more dialog use cases within the luis agent

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. I only showed how to use the "I_mts-bot-809f" as an example. if you have further cases, you'll have to build them into the switch case yourself.